# Linux bash MySQL load infile

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, terminal

I'm trying to simplify a load data local infile, by putting it into a .sh file, and bash to run it.

Here is my count_portal.sh file

```
mysql -h host -u root -p password 
load data local infile
"/workplace/user/dump/count_portal.txt" 
replace into table test.icqa_count_portal 
fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 lines;
```

And here is my bash script

bash `/home/user/Desktop/count_portal.sh` I get an output that doesn't do what it is designed to do. When I simply make the count_portal.sh contain `mysql -h host` it longs in when running the script.

Comment: so what's the questions?

Comment: How I would go about making this .sh work. Currently it doesn't read anything after mysql-h host -u root -p password. It appears load data local infile isn't recognized or not working. Although it does work independently while connected to mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is my file.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mysql --host=host --user=root --password=password --database=test<<EOFMYSQL
load data local infile '/workplace/user/ETLdump/count_portal.txt' replace INTO TABLE count_portal fields terminated by '\t' LINES
TERMINATED BY '\n' ignore 1 lines;
EOFMYSQL
```

Works flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

missed -e ?

```
mysql -h host -u root -ppassword dbname -e "load data local infile '/workplace/user/dump/count_portal.txt' replace into table test.icqa_count_portal fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 lines;"
```

Comment: Tried this same result, just gave me a bunch of options of example commands.

Comment: @Spartacus38 Emm, two more things, should no space between -p and pasword, and you missed db name.

Comment: That did, something, it generates a new line. dquote >

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space between the user and password switches.  So it would be something like:

```
mysql -h host -uroot -ppassword etc....
```

The spaces seem to cause problems for me when doing similar things inside bash scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @PasteBT, his answer should work well. I think there are escape problem or shell variable is empty.

Have you tried this?:

```
echo "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/workplace/user/dump/count_portal.txt' REPLACE INTO TABLE test.icqa_count_portal FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;" | mysql -h host -u root -ppassword
```

and you original shell script is wrong. could you post again what did you do?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u<username> -p<password> -h<hostname> <db_name> --local_infile=1 -e "use <db_name>" -e"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '<path/file_name>' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE <table_name>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'"
```